# trying to delete images from p:imgswitch

Tags: jsf, primefaces

sorry, i speak english a little.
my question:
I have created a p:imgswitch. I want to attach a delete-button to each image so i added it but it doesn't work!. i have tried to put commandbutton inside of graphicimage and graphicimage inside of commandbutton or separated but i achieve the same result. if i click next-button first it´s showed the image only, the delete-button is showed when i click next again. one component each time i press next or prev button instead of both components showed at the same time. i will be very grateful if you can help me, thanks!!!!!!!

this is my code:

```
           <p:imageSwitch widgetVar="switcher" id="manuelSwitcher"
                    slideshowAuto="false" effect="none">
                    <ui:repeat value="#{vegetalesMb.images}" var="image"
                        id="manuelSwitcherImages">

                        <p:graphicImage id="fotos" value="/Images/#{image}"
                            alt="Descripción #{image}" title="#{image}">
                            <p:commandButton action="#{vegetalesMb.buttonBorrarFoto}">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{image}"
                                    target="#{vegetalesMb.image}" />
                            </p:commandButton>
                        </p:graphicImage>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:imageSwitch>
                <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('switcher').previous();"
                    icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-w" id="prev" />
                <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('switcher').next();"
                    icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-e" id="next" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, the way I solved it was to put both the `p:commandButton` and the `p:graphicImage` tags inside a `p:panelGrid` tag. You just have to make sure to update the `p:imageSwitch` component inside your `p:commandButton`.
Hope this helps!

```
<p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
    <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('switcher').previous();"
                     icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-w" id="prev"/>
    <p:commandButton type="button" onclick="PF('switcher').next();"
                     icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-e" id="next"/>

</p:panelGrid>
<p:imageSwitch effect="none" widgetVar="switcher" id="manualSwitcher"
               slideshowAuto="false">
    <ui:repeat value="#{myController.imageList}" var="image" id="manualSwitcherImages">
        <p:panelGrid columns="1" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank">
            <p:commandButton action="#{myController.removeImage(image)}" update=":mainForm:manualSwitcher" icon="fa fa-remove"/>
            <p:graphicImage value="#{image.stream}" cache="false" title="#{image.label}" stream="false" width="400" height="240"/>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:imageSwitch>
```